# How to change button background in Android in Neumorphism design concept?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-button

I am working in Neumorphism based designs in my project. I am using this library https://github.com/fornewid/neumorphism for Neumorphism effect. My issue is I can't able to change the background of the button or any other views.

This is my layout file

**activity_neumorphism.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/screen_background_gradient"
    tools:context=".NeumorphismActivity">


    <soup.neumorphism.NeumorphButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        style="@style/Widget.Neumorph.Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/res_transparent_yellow_roundedfilled_corner"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/normal_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/res_transparent_yellow_roundedfilled_corner"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/normal_button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:text="THIS IS NORMAL BUTTON"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:text="THIS IS Neumorphism effect BUTTON"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have two buttons in this xml. One is normal button and another is neumorphism. I have set background for both but it's only applies for normal button.

Below given is drawable file for background

**res_transparent_yellow_roundedfilled_corner.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:radius="10dp"
        />


    <gradient
        android:startColor="#C8A800"
        android:endColor="#FFD80A"/>
</shape>
```

Below given is styles.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Widget.Neumorph.Button" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceButton</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">72dip</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">112dip</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/res_transparent_yellow_roundedfilled_corner</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/design_btn_padding_left</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/design_btn_padding_right</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/design_btn_padding_top</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/design_btn_padding_bottom</item>
        <item name="android:stateListAnimator">@animator/button_state_list_anim_neumorph</item>
        <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
        <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="neumorph_inset">@dimen/design_default_inset</item>
        <item name="neumorph_shadowElevation">6dp</item>
        <item name="neumorph_shadowColorLight">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="neumorph_shadowColorDark">#000000</item>
        <item name="neumorph_shapeType">flat</item>
        <item name="neumorph_shapeAppearance">@style/ShapeAppearance.Neumorph.Button</item>

    </style>

    <style name="ShapeAppearance.Neumorph.Button" parent="">

        <item name="background"> @drawable/res_transparent_yellow_roundedfilled_corner</item>

    </style>
</resources>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this property to change background `app:neumorph_backgroundColor="@color/background_color"` in your xml

if not working, there is one method inside `NeumorphButton` is `setBackgroundDrawable`. you can set drawable programmatically

**Edit**

you can't set the custom background in this lib because it says

> Setting a custom background is not supported.

Comment: app:neumorph_backgroundColor -> This attribute changes the background color of that button. But what I need is, I want to add drawable background to that button so that I can customize shapes in xml. This setBackgroundDrawable is not working.

Comment: can you please post a screenshot how exactly you need?

Comment: Added. I want the same background which is used in normal button for Neumorphism button also

Comment: you can't set the custom background in this lib because it says `Setting a custom background is not supported.`

Comment: Is there any other lib for neumorphism?

Comment: here are some good libs in java https://github.com/topics/neumorphism?l=java